# How is the 'E/e' in hexadecimal differentiated from the 'E/e' in exponential form in a hexadecimal floating point literal?

Tags: c

In C, if I want a floating point literal x to be in hexadecimal form and have an exponential value, it will be denoted as this:

```
float x = 0X2aE+10;
```

Where the 0x is used to denote it's in hexadecimal, and the 2a for the hexadecimal characters, and the E+10 for the number into ten to the power ten.
However, will the compiler know it's not 2aE that's representing the hexadecimal digits (since hexadecimal uses a to e for 10-15) and +10 is just adding ten to the number? And if it doesn't, what's the fix?

Comment: `0X2aE+10` is an `unsigned` computation, evaluated before the value `686` (decimal) is assigned to the `float`.

Comment: http://codepad.org/DaR86CWu gives me an error

Comment: Both `clang` and `gcc` return `error: invalid suffix '+10' on integer constant`

Comment: @WeatherVane: I'm afraid you are mistaken: `0X2aE+10` is a valid preprocessor token that does not translate into a valid C token, it should not be parsed as an expression.

Comment: @chqrlie thanks, but I compiled it before commenting: `0X2aE+10` prints `696` and `42E+10` prints `420000000000` (using `double` not `float`). MSVC did not understand when I used `p` as in `0X2ap+10`. I do not know what you mean by "preprocessor token", I see `0X2aE+10` as being `0x2AE + 10`

Comment: @WeatherVane: Interesting! One more departure from the Standard for MSVC.  Whether or not it supports hexadecimal floats, it should parse `0X2aE+10` as a preprocessing number (*pp-number*) which is translated in phase 7 into an integer constant or a floating point constant.  It should not be reinterpreted or parsed differently as your test seem to indicate.

Comment: This behavior goes back to C89 aka Ansi-C: *6.4.8 Preprocessing numbers: A preprocessing number begins with a digit optionally preceded by a period (.) and may be followed by letters, underscores, digits, periods, and e+, e-, E+, E-, p+, p-, P+, or P- character sequences*

Comment: @chqrlie I still do not understand why `0X2aE+10` has caused (others) a compiler error, when it is seemingly identical to `0x2AE + 10`, a perfectly valid expression.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Read the C Standard paragraph 6.4.8: `0X2aE+10` is parsed by the preprocessor as a single token, namely a *pp-number* or preprocessor number.  The rationale for this awkward behavior is to allow the creation of hexadecimal and floating point constants via token pasting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`0X2aE+10` is a valid preprocessor token that does not translate into a valid C token, hence the compilation error.  C99 Hexadecimal floating point numbers use `P` or `p` as the exponent marker, as in:

```
float x = 0X2aP+10;
```

Which has the value `0x2a * 1024` -> `43008`.

For those who do not know about preprocessing numbers:

> **6.4.8 Preprocessing numbers**
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> pp-number:
>       digit
>       . digit
>       pp-number digit
>       pp-number identifier-nondigit
>       pp-number e sign
>       pp-number E sign
>       pp-number p sign
>       pp-number P sign
>       pp-number .
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> A preprocessing number begins with a digit optionally preceded by a period (.) and may be followed by valid identifier characters and the character sequences `e+`, `e-`, `E+`, `E-`, `p+`, `p-`, `P+`, or `P-`.
>
> Preprocessing number tokens lexically include all floating and integer constant tokens.
>
> **Semantics**
>
> A preprocessing number does not have type or a value; it acquires both after a successful conversion (as part of translation phase 7) to a floating constant token or an integer constant token.

Answer (score 5):

If you see e.g. [this floating point literal reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant) you will see that hexadecimal floating point values need the `p` or `P` infix to denote the exponent.

So the definition should look like

```
float x = 0X2ap10;
```

Comment: Oh, ok, was not aware of the p. Is there a reason that it's converted into a double at first and not a float?

Comment: @Aryanpoonacha My mistake, I just wrote `double` because it's the default floating point type, it will of course be a `float`.

Comment: Also, on a side note, shouldn't it be 0x2ap+10? Or does 0x2ap10 default to 0x2ap+10?

Comment: @Aryanpoonacha If you write the number ten on a paper, would you write it as "+10"? :) The plus is implied in all numbers unless there's a minus sign before them.

Answer (score 5):

Hex floats use `p` as the exponent marker:

```
float x = 0x2ap+10;
```

That's actually a `double` value, though. If you want a `float` literal, you need an `f` suffix:

```
float x = 0x2ap+10f;
```